# How to check that two conditions of 5 are true?

Tags: drupal, drupal-rules

I want to check that 2 of 5 fields are filled, but I don't know how.

If I put this in conditions, that only checks one of the conditions is true:

OR

- field1 is not empty
- field2 is not empty
- field3 is not empty
- field4 is not empty
- field5 is not empty

there is an easier way that the following?

- field1 is not empty
- field2 is not empty

OR

- field1 is not empty
- field3 is not empty

OR

- field1 is not empty
- field4 is not empty

OR

- field1 is not empty
- field5 is not empty

OR

- field2 is not empty
- field3 is not empty

OR

- field2 is not empty
- field4 is not empty
  (...)

Answer (score 1):

2 For loops

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
     for(int j=i+1;j<5;j++){
      if(field[i]==true&&field[j]==true)
       return true;
     }
    }
```

EDIT: 
You replace the statements for your needs.
And you must store the fields in an array.
Credits to zolyboy for the i+1 thing :)

Comment: j variable should start from i not from 0

Comment: why to test field[1] == true && field[2] == true and after that field[2] == true && field[1] == true ? it's totally the same thing, if you put instead of 0 i+1 then you will not do the same multiple times

Answer (score 0):

In SQL I would to it this way:

```
select if(if(field1='',0,1)+ if(field2='',0,1)+ if(field3='',0,1)+ if(field4='',0,1)+ if(field5='',0,1)=2) true else false end ...
```

In other language it could be something like:

```
int a = (field1.equals(""))0:1;
int b = (field2.equals(""))0:1;
int c = (field3.equals(""))0:1;
int d = (field4.equals(""))0:1;
int e = (field5.equals(""))0:1;

boolean result= (a+b+c+d+e==2)?true:false;
```

With above code you can easily use it for 3 of 5, 4 of 5, 7 of 10 conditions etc...